# How to handle invalid json in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, try-catch

I want to catch invalid json. So for example if I receive `"usern": "James"` instead of `"username": "James"`. I want to respond with a `400` status code.

```
exports.create_user = async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.create({
      username: username,
    });
    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(503).end();
  }
  res.status(400).json({ msg: "Syntax error" });
};
```

Now this doesn't catch invalid json, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
exports.create_user = async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  if(!username) { // if username is falsy e.g: undefined|null
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "Syntax error" });
    return;
  }
  try {
    const user = await User.create({
      username: username,
    });
    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(503).end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Really, isn't there a better way to handle this? Imagine if I have 5 keys in body.

Comment: You can try using class-validator or other validation packages, such as joi to make it a bit easier.